# Python decoding message object of email but got 3 "From" headers

Tags: python, header, decoding, imaplib

### Problem

I'm trying to print email metadata using python imap.lib. The message object I got from `imap4.fectch` is supposed to contain proper header information, but one specific email returns 3 "From" header instead of 1.

### What I've tried

I printed out results of `array = decode_header(msg.get("From"))`, for normal emails it returns something like this `[('"Agnes Lee (ADVS)" <agnes.lee@xxx.com>', None)]`, but one email would return 3 "From" headers in byte format `[(b'"', None), (b'\xe5\x8c\x97\xe9\x83\xa8\xe5\x8c\xba', 'utf-8'), (b'" <datacollection.xxx@xxxx.com>', None)]`.
Apparently `array[2]` instead of `array[0]` in this case contains the email address I want, but it's in byte format and no charset is provided to decode. I wonder why this is the case for some mails that contains 3 From.

### My code

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SERVER, 993)
M.login(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
rsp, data = M.select('INBOX')
data = int(data[0])
res, msg = M.fetch(data, '(RFC822)') #fetch last email recieved
for response in msg:
 if isinstance(response, tuple):
   msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
   # decode the email subject
   From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]   
   if isinstance(From, bytes):
     From = From.decode(encoding)
     print(From)
```

Comment: It isn't actually three From headers, it's a From header which has pieces in three different charsets.  The first part is empty, the second part is `b'\xe5\x8c\x97\xe9\x83\xa8\xe5\x8c\xba'.decode('utf-8')` -> `'北部区'`, and the third part is just in ASCII.  I believe the python email library has a way to do this decoding for you, I think email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(...)).

Comment: Great! I wonder why is it like this though, since eventually I will have to implement a handler to deal with this exception( has 3 from objects)

Comment: Because MIME (and email in general) is an abomination of a dozen different standards that are all excessively backwards compatible with 7-bit-ascii clients from the last millennium.  This is a result of a header encoding called Encoded Words from RFC 2047, where each word can be in a different encoding.